# Using React-Redux Form Fields with Date Range in react-datepicker

Tags: reactjs, forms, redux, field

From the react-datepicker:

https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/blob/master/docs-site/src/examples/date_range.jsx#L4

For this :

**datePicker.js**

```
const { fields, input , meta } = this.props;
const { touched, error, warning } = meta || {}

...

return (

<DatePicker 
    selected={this.state.startDate ? this.state.startDate : undefined} 
    selectsStart 
    startDate={this.state.startDate} 
    endDate={this.state.endDate} 
    onChange={this.handleChangeStart} 
    dateFormat="DD/MM/YYYY"
/>
<span> to </span>  
<DatePicker 
    selected={this.state.endDate ? this.state.endDate : undefined} 
    selectsEnd 
    startDate={this.state.startDate}  
    endDate={this.state.endDate} 
    onChange={this.handleChangeEnd} 
    dateFormat="DD/MM/YYYY"
/>
{touched && ( /* << how to declare the meta respectively ? */  
(error && <span>ERR</span>)||
(warning && <span>WARN</span>)
)}

...

)
```

As there are 2 field inputs, I decided to use "Fields" in redux form, but how should I specify the input name and value I get in the component?

I try this, but the names and values seems to be wrong, and I don't know how to declare the name and get the value from the component.

**callDatePicker.js**

```
<Fields 
   labelNode={<Label>Range</Label>}
   labelStartDate="Start Date"
   labelEndDate="End Date"
   names={["nameStartDate", "nameEndDate"]}
   values={[ this.props.start , this.props.end]} << this returns wrong saying the value is object instead of string..
   component={ControlledDateRangePicker}
/>
```

Comment: Htnew because you are new I post this information:) If one of the answers below answered your question, the way this site works works, you'd "accept" the answer, more here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers  But only if your question really has been answered. If not, consider adding more details to the question.

Comment: Thanks ~ but using the 'Field' instead of 'Fields' causing the function call problems, as each Field call different functions : ' ( So I am still struggling the method

Comment: could you reproduce your error on any online sandbox for example here: https://codesandbox.io/ ?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply again, and today I use 2 "Field" component separately, and call the handle function in parent using callback, finally it works. Thanks so much for your idea <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two separated fields:

```
    <Field
        name="startDatePicker"
        label="Start Date"
        fieldName="startDate"
        component={ControlledDateRangePicker}
        ...
      />
    <Field
        name="endDatePicker"
        label="End Date"
        fieldName="endDate"
        component={ControlledDateRangePicker}
        ...
      />
```

And in ControlledDateRangePicker use only one DatePicker component, that should be generic.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but when I separate the Fields as Field, how should I manage the onChange method which are calling different function ? Thanks > <!!

Answer (score 0):

This has been a thorn in my side for the past few days.

I was trying to automatically adjust an `endDate` field in Redux Form when the user selected a new `startDate` in order to ensure the fields are never more than 60 days apart.

To accomplish this we utilized Redux Form's `change` prop within `onChange` from ReactDatepicker: https://redux-form.com/8.0.4/docs/api/props.md/#-code-change-field-string-value-any-function-code-

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.
Use two Feilds for start date and end date. Unless you wont get two form values as start-date and end-date separately.

Just go through my code. you will understand the process.

```
      <Field
        isRequired
        name="leaseStartDate"
        component={renderDateComponent}
        label="Start Date of Lease"
        labelWidth={12}
        inputWidth={12}
        maxDate`enter code here`
        className="form-control"
        errorClass="error"
      />

      <Field
        isRequired
        name="leaseEndDate"
        component={renderDateComponent}
        label="End Date of Lease"
        labelWidth={12}
        inputWidth={12}
        minDate
        className="form-control"
        errorClass="error"
      />
```

use a class component for your datepicker.js
use mapStateToProps to get updated form values of StartDate and EndDate.
So you can use componentDidUpdate to update the date if there is any change in the previous props.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  formValues: getFormValues('unifyAddEditSiteDetailsForm')(state)
});


class RenderDateComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      startDate: null,
      endDate: null
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const {formValues} = this.props;

    if (formValues !== prevProps.formValues) {
      this.updateDate(formValues);
    }
  }

  updateDate = formData => {
    this.setState({
      startDate: formData.leaseStartDate,
      endDate: formData.leaseEndDate
    });
  }

  render() {
    const {
      input,
      labelWidth,
      isRequired,
      label,
      inputWidth,
      isIcon,
      iconClass,
      maxDate,
      minDate,
      meta: {
        touched,
        error }
    } = this.props;

    const { startDate, endDate } = this.state;

    return (
      <FormGroup 
        className="hours-form-group" 
        validationState={(touched && error) ? 'error' : null}
      >
        <DatePicker
          {...input}
          className="datepicker-input"
          value={input.value && moment(input.value).format('MMM DD, YYYY')}
          onBlur={() => input.onBlur(moment(input.value).format('MMM DD, YYYY'))}
          autoComplete='off'
          maxDate={maxDate ? endDate : null}
          minDate={minDate ? startDate : null}
        />
        {touched && error && <HelpBlock>{error}</HelpBlock>}
      </Col>
    </FormGroup>
    );
  }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(RenderDateComponent);
```